# MongoDB find() and count() returning different number of documents

Tags: mongodb

I am running a simple find() query in a sharded MongoDB cluster (through a mongos instance) mongo shell:

```
mongos> db.widgets.find({"_id" : ObjectId("53b76d2569702d63bb670000")}).count()
    
mongos> db.widgets.find({"_id" : ObjectId("53b76d2569702d63bb670000")})
    
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53b76d2569702d63bb670000"),
  "page_id" : ObjectId("53b76d2569702d63bb660000"),
  "user_id" : ObjectId("53a012fc69702d69ebc50200"),
  "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-07-05T03:12:37.279Z"),
  "created_at" : ISODate("2014-07-05T03:12:37.279Z")
}

mongos> it
no cursor
mongos>
```

As you can see, `find().count()` returns 2, but `find()` only returns one document.
And there is no cursor to iterate.

What would be the reason for this discrepancy?

Thank you.

Comment: I can't see the result (2) of count(), btw, have you tried using countDocuments({}) instead of count()? Post full output so I can help you. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/